# What is the difference between find_element_by_tag_name and find_elements_by_tag_name?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

What is the difference between the function with the singular name and the one with the plural name?

```
find_element_by_name
find_elements_by_name
```

and

```
find_element_by_tag_name
find_elements_by_tag_name
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm not all that familiar with python and selenium but most DOM functions act the same way.

`find_element_by_name` should return an element who's name attribute matches the name (the first instance found)

```
<input name="username" type="text" value="Enter Username" />
```

`find_elements_by_name` will return a collection/array of matching elements

```
<input name="continue" type="submit" value="Login" />
<input name="continue" type="button" value="Clear" />
```

`find_element_by_tag_name` will be similar only returning the first instance of an element with the matching tag name.

```
find_element_by_tag_name("a") // return the first anchor
```

`find_elements_by_tag_name` will again return a collection/array of matching tag names.

If its possible to chain these commands, or call them on stored elements the result from `get_element(s)_*` functions will be relative to node its called on.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
       <a href="#1">Example 1</a>
       <a href="#2">Example 2</a>
    </div>
    <span>
       <a href="#3">Example 3</a>
       <a href="#4">Example 4</a>
    </span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Example

`find_element_by_tag_name("a")` == `Example 1`

`find_element_by_tag_name("span").find_element_by_tag_name("a")` == `Example 3`

Iteration over collection/array

```
links = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")

for link in links
 # link should be a Selenium WebElement?
```

if in doubt you can just dump the whole result to see what is in it.

[Debugging python object/properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192109/is-there-a-function-in-python-to-print-all-the-current-properties-and-values-of)

Comment: now according to you when you would use `find_elements_by_tag_name` and get the collections,then how would you iterate over it to get reach to the desired `anchor` element?

Comment: the the edit at the end, my python is poor at best. I would suggest you debug the result from the function and see what you get.

Comment: @NickSlash You may not know Python or Selenium well, but this is absolutely correct.  There's one other subtle effect - find_element_by_whatever may involve a long wait if "implicit waits" are enabled and the item doesn't exist. But find_elements_by_whatever will return immediately, with a collection containing 0 elements.

Answer (score 0):

### find_element_by_tag_name(tag_name)

The function with the singular name is [`find_element_by_tag_name(tag_name)`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_tag_name) which finds an element by the tag name and returns the element.

- Details:

  ```
  find_element_by_tag_name(tag_name)        

  Args :  
      name - name of html tag (eg: h1, a, span)

  Returns :   
      WebElement - the element if it was found

  Raises :    
      NoSuchElementException - if the element wasn’t found
  ```
- Usage :

  ```
  element = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("h1")
  ```

---

### find_elements_by_tag_name(tag_name)

The function with the plural name is [`find_elements_by_tag_name(tag_name)`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_tag_name) which find elements by tag name and returns a list.

- Details:

  ```
  find_elements_by_tag_name(tag_name): 

  Args :  
      name - name of html tag (eg: h1, a, span)

  Returns :
      list of WebElements - a list with elements if any was found. An empty list if not
  ```
- Usage :

  ```
  elements = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("h1")
  ```