# Finding all child elements in an html page using python selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I want to extract all h2 elements of the div element. The code that I've used is this:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://www.mmorpg.com/play-now")
time.sleep(2)
item_list_new=[]
link = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='freegamelist']")
names = link.find_element_by_tag_name('h2')
x = names.text
item_list_new.append(x)
print(item_list_new)
```

But when I run this, I only get the first 'h2' element of the div element.
Can somebody tell me what am I doing wrong and also please guide me with the correct way of doing it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to get all header values as below:

```
link = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='freegamelist']")
names = link.find_elements_by_tag_name('h2')
item_list_new = [x.text for x in names]
print(item_list_new)
```

or you can simplify

```
names = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='freegamelist']//h2")
item_list_new = [x.text for x in names]
print(item_list_new)
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to write `names = link.find_elements_by_tag_name('h2')`

Your code should be

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://www.mmorpg.com/play-now")
time.sleep(2)
item_list_new=[]
link = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='freegamelist']")
names = link.find_elements_by_tag_name('h2')
x = names.text
item_list_new.append(x)
print(item_list_new)
```

`find_element_by_tag_name` gives the first element and `find_elements_by_tag_name` gives all the matching elements

Answer (score 0):

You actually want to use the function `find_elements_by_tag_name` that sounds almost similar, as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14090587/10484131).