# Print all non-iterable properties of object

Tags: python, debugging

[As mentioned on SE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192109/is-there-a-function-in-python-to-print-all-the-current-properties-and-values-of) one can get all the iterable properties of an object with either `dir(someObject)` or `someObject.__dict__`. **How does one get the non-iterable properties?** Some libraries, such as Reqests, return objects with non-iterable properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's **impossible** to list all attributes reliably in every circumstance, for the simple fact that attributes can be defined at runtime using `__getattr__` or `__getattribute__`.

For example the following class has a 50% chance to create a new attribute or to raise an `AttributeError`.

```
import random

class AttributeGenerator(object):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if random.random() < 0.5:
            setattr(self, attr, None)
            return getattr(self, attr) 
        else:
            raise AttributeError(attr)
```

The only general-purpose functions to get attributes from an instance are `dir()` and `vars()`.

Note that `dir()` by default combines the result obtained by `__dict__`, `__slots__` and the class' `__dict__` etc. Classes can redefine how `dir()` works on their instances by defining the `__dir__` method, however I've never seen it used.
If this method exists and "hides" some attributes for some reason you can simply do
something like:

```
attributes = list(object.__dict__.keys()) + list(obj.__slots__) + list(type(obj).__dict__)
```

(with the appropriate error checking!) in order to obtain the default's `dir()` output.

---

This said, if you are interested in a particular library then there might be some method specific for that library that works reliably.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pprint from pprint 
pprint (vars(<object name>))
```

Comment: Thank you Monty. However, the non-iterable attributes are not exposed with `vars()`.