# How to put my dataset in a .pkl file in the exact format and data structure used in "mnist.pkl.gz"?

Tags: python, theano, pickle, mnist, dbn

I'm trying to use the Theano library in python to do some experiments with Deep Belief Networks. I use the code in this address: [DBN full code](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/code/DBN.py). This code use the [MNIST Handwritten database](http://deeplearning.net/data/mnist/mnist.pkl.gz). This file is already in pickle format. 
It is unpicked in:

- train_set
- valid_set
- test_set

Which is further unpickled in:

- train_set_x, train_set_y = train_set
- valid_set_x, valid_set_y = valid_set
- test_set_x, test_set_y = test_set

Please can someone give me the code that constructs this dataset in order to create my own?
The DBN example I use needs the data in this format and I don't know how to do it.
if anyone has any ideas how to fix this, please tell me.

**Here is my code:**

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
import os
from pprint import pprint
import numpy as np
import gzip, cPickle
import theano.tensor as T
from theano import function


os.system("cls")

filename = "completeData.txt"


f = open(filename,"r")
X = []
Y = []

for line in f:
        line = line.strip('\n')  
        b = line.split(';')
        b[0] = float(b[0])
        b[1] = float(b[1])
        b[2] = float(b[2])
        b[3] = float(b[3])
        b[4] = float(b[4])
        b[5] = float(b[5])
        b[6] = float(b[6])
        b[7] = float(b[7])
        b[8] = float(b[8])
        b[9] = float(b[9])
        b[10] = float(b[10])
        b[11] = float(b[11])
        b[12] = float(b[12])
        b[13] = float(b[13])
        b[14] = float(b[14])
        b[15] = float(b[15])
        b[17] = int(b[17])
        X.append(b[:16])
        Y.append(b[17])

Len = len(X);
X = np.asmatrix(X)
Y = np.asarray(Y)

sizes = [0.8, 0.1, 0.1]
arr_index = int(sizes[0]*Len)
arr_index2_start = arr_index + 1
arr_index2_end = arr_index + int(sizes[1]*Len)
arr_index3_start = arr_index2_start + 1

"""
train_set_x = np.array(X[:arr_index])
train_set_y = np.array(Y[:arr_index])

val_set_x = np.array(X[arr_index2_start:arr_index2_end])
val_set_y = np.array(Y[arr_index2_start:arr_index2_end])

test_set_x = np.array(X[arr_index3_start:])
test_set_y = np.array(X[arr_index3_start:])

train_set = train_set_x, train_set_y
val_set = val_set_x, val_set_y
test_set = test_set_x, test_set_y
"""
x = T.dmatrix('x')
z = x
t_mat = function([x],z)

y = T.dvector('y')
k = y
t_vec = function([y],k)

train_set_x = t_mat(X[:arr_index].T)
train_set_y = t_vec(Y[:arr_index])
val_set_x = t_mat(X[arr_index2_start:arr_index2_end].T)
val_set_y = t_vec(Y[arr_index2_start:arr_index2_end])
test_set_x = t_mat(X[arr_index3_start:].T)
test_set_y = t_vec(Y[arr_index3_start:])

train_set = train_set_x, train_set_y
val_set = val_set_x, val_set_y
test_set = test_set_x, test_set_y

dataset = [train_set, val_set, test_set]

f = gzip.open('..\..\..\data\dex.pkl.gz','wb')
cPickle.dump(dataset, f, protocol=-1)
f.close()

pprint(train_set_x.shape)

print('Finished\n')
```

Comment: You can simply implement Python based on the description below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A .pkl file is not necessary to adapt code from the Theano tutorial to your own data. You only need to mimic their data structure.

## Quick fix

Look for the following lines. It's line 303 on **DBN.py**.

```
datasets = load_data(dataset)
train_set_x, train_set_y = datasets[0]
```

Replace with your own `train_set_x` and `train_set_y`.

```
my_x = []
my_y = []
with open('path_to_file', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        my_list = line.split(' ') # replace with your own separator instead
        my_x.append(my_list[1:-1]) # omitting identifier in [0] and target in [-1]
        my_y.append(my_list[-1])
train_set_x = theano.shared(numpy.array(my_x, dtype='float64'))
train_set_y = theano.shared(numpy.array(my_y, dtype='float64'))
```

Adapt this to your input data and the code you're using.

The same thing works for **cA.py**, **dA.py** and **SdA.py** but they only use `train_set_x`.

Look for places such as `n_ins=28 * 28` where mnist image sizes are hardcoded. Replace `28 * 28` with your own number of columns.

## Explanation

This is where you put your data in a format that Theano can work with.

```
train_set_x = theano.shared(numpy.array(my_x, dtype='float64'))
train_set_y = theano.shared(numpy.array(my_y, dtype='float64'))
```

`shared()` turns a numpy array into the Theano format designed for efficiency on GPUs.

`dtype='float64'` is expected in Theano arrays.

More details on [basic tensor functionality](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html).

## .pkl file

The .pkl file is a way to save your data structure.

You can create your own.

```
import cPickle
f = file('my_data.pkl', 'wb')
    cPickle.dump((train_set_x, train_set_y), f, protocol=cPickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
f.close()
```

More details on [loading and saving](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/loading_and_saving.html).

Answer (score 5):

The pickled file represents a tuple of 3 lists : the training set, the validation set and the testing set. (train, val, test)

- Each of the three lists is a pair formed from a list of images and a list of class labels for each of the images.
- An image is represented as numpy 1-dimensional array of 784 (28 x 28) float values between 0 and 1 (0 stands for black, 1 for white).
- The labels are numbers between 0 and 9 indicating which digit the image represents.

Answer (score 3):

This can help:

```
from PIL import Image
from numpy import genfromtxt
import gzip, cPickle
from glob import glob
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
Data, y = dir_to_dataset("trainMNISTForm\\*.BMP","trainLabels.csv")
# Data and labels are read 

train_set_x = Data[:2093]
val_set_x = Data[2094:4187]
test_set_x = Data[4188:6281]
train_set_y = y[:2093]
val_set_y = y[2094:4187]
test_set_y = y[4188:6281]
# Divided dataset into 3 parts. I had 6281 images.

train_set = train_set_x, train_set_y
val_set = val_set_x, val_set_y
test_set = test_set_x, val_set_y

dataset = [train_set, val_set, test_set]

f = gzip.open('file.pkl.gz','wb')
cPickle.dump(dataset, f, protocol=2)
f.close()
```

This is the function I used. May change according to your file details.

```
def dir_to_dataset(glob_files, loc_train_labels=""):
    print("Gonna process:\n\t %s"%glob_files)
    dataset = []
    for file_count, file_name in enumerate( sorted(glob(glob_files),key=len) ):
        image = Image.open(file_name)
        img = Image.open(file_name).convert('LA') #tograyscale
        pixels = [f[0] for f in list(img.getdata())]
        dataset.append(pixels)
        if file_count % 1000 == 0:
            print("\t %s files processed"%file_count)
    # outfile = glob_files+"out"
    # np.save(outfile, dataset)
    if len(loc_train_labels) > 0:
        df = pd.read_csv(loc_train_labels)
        return np.array(dataset), np.array(df["Class"])
    else:
        return np.array(dataset)
```