# Extract images from .idx3-ubyte file or GZIP via Python

Tags: python, mnist

I have created a simple function for facerecognition by using the facerecognizer from OpenCV. It works all fine with images from people.

Now I would like to make a test by using handwritten characters instead of people. I came across MNIST dataset, but they store images in a weird file which I have never seen before.

I simply need to extract a few images from:

```
train-images.idx3-ubyte
```

and save them in a folder as `.gif`

Or am I missunderstand this MNIST thing. If yes where could I get such a dataset?

**EDIT**

I also have the gzip file:

```
train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
```

I am trying to read the content, but `show()` does not work and if I `read()` I see random symbols.

```
images = gzip.open("train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz", 'rb')
print images.read()
```

**EDIT**

Managed to get some usefull output by using:

```
with gzip.open('train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz','r') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        print('got line', line)
```

Somehow I have to convert this now to an image, output:

[image]

Comment: `python-mnist` package on PyPI has some code can do the job.

Comment: The file format of `.idx3-ubyte` is described in [THE MNIST DATABASE](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) page.

Comment: If anyone is wondering where you can find all these dataset? Here is the link -> http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/

Answer (score 80):

Download the training/test images and labels:

- train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz:  training set images
- train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz:  training set labels
- t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz:   test set images
- t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz:   test set labels

And uncompress them in a workdir, say `samples/`.

Get the [python-mnist](https://github.com/sorki/python-mnist) package from PyPi:

```
pip install python-mnist
```

Import the `mnist` package and read the training/test images:

```
from mnist import MNIST

mndata = MNIST('samples')

images, labels = mndata.load_training()
# or
images, labels = mndata.load_testing()
```

To display an image to the console:

```
index = random.randrange(0, len(images))  # choose an index ;-)
print(mndata.display(images[index]))
```

You'll get something like this:

```
............................
............................
............................
............................
............................
.................@@.........
..............@@@@@.........
............@@@@............
..........@@................
..........@.................
...........@................
...........@................
...........@...@............
...........@@@@@.@..........
...........@@@...@@.........
...........@@.....@.........
..................@.........
..................@@........
..................@@........
..................@.........
.................@@.........
...........@.....@..........
...........@....@@..........
............@@@@............
.............@..............
............................
............................
............................
```

Explanation:

- Each *image* of the *images* list is a Python `list` of unsigned bytes.
- The *labels* is an Python `array` of unsigned bytes.

Comment: note that when you extract the files, rename the dots to `-` (or you will get a file missing error), for example `t10k-images.idx3-ubyte` must be renamed to `t10k-images-idx3-ubyte`

Answer (score 62):

(Using only matplotlib, gzip and numpy)

Extract image data:

```
import gzip
f = gzip.open('train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz','r')

image_size = 28
num_images = 5

import numpy as np
f.read(16)
buf = f.read(image_size * image_size * num_images)
data = np.frombuffer(buf, dtype=np.uint8).astype(np.float32)
data = data.reshape(num_images, image_size, image_size, 1)
```

Print images:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
image = np.asarray(data[2]).squeeze()
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Print first 50 labels:

```
f = gzip.open('train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz','r')
f.read(8)
for i in range(0,50):   
    buf = f.read(1)
    labels = np.frombuffer(buf, dtype=np.uint8).astype(np.int64)
    print(labels)
```

Comment: Is the f.read(16) and   f.read(8) skipping non-image information?

Comment: Rewritten now for easier understanding. Yes, the two first bytes (f.read(8)) is always 0. Read more about the IDX(MNIST)-format here: http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/

Comment: But you wrote 100 labels, but changed it to 50?

Comment: Thanks, fixed. Felt it did't ad extra value to display a lot of data on the screen when it was only vertically. Had its purpose when it was horizontal+vertical stacked.

Comment: Hi, if I want to show images from  `train-labels-idx1-ubyte` (already without .gz) then what I have to do?

Comment: @mostafiz67 Hi, you can do `f = open('train-labels-idx1-ubyte', 'rb')`. That way you will be just opening the file with python's open function in binary mode.

Answer (score 20):

You could actually use the [idx2numpy](https://pypi.org/project/idx2numpy/) package available at PyPI. It's *extremely* simple to use and directly converts the data to numpy arrays. 
Here's what you have to do:

### Downloading the data

Download the MNIST dataset from the [official website](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/).
If you're using Linux then you can use [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) to get it from command line itself. Just run:

```sh
wget http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
wget http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
wget http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
wget http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
```

### Decompressing the data

Unzip or decompress the data. On Linux, you could use [gzip](https://www.gnu.org/software/gzip/)

Ultimately, you should have the following files:

```sh
data/train-images-idx3-ubyte
data/train-labels-idx1-ubyte
data/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte
data/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte
```

The prefix `data/` is just because I've extracted them into a folder named `data`. Your question looks like you're well done till here, so keep reading.

### Using idx2numpy

Here's a simple python code to read everything from the decompressed files as numpy arrays.

```py
import idx2numpy
import numpy as np
file = 'data/train-images-idx3-ubyte'
arr = idx2numpy.convert_from_file(file)
# arr is now a np.ndarray type of object of shape 60000, 28, 28
```

You can now use it with OpenCV juts the same way how you display any other image, using something like

```py
cv.imshow("Image", arr[4])
```

To install idx2numpy, you can use PyPI (`pip` package manager). Simply run the command:

```sh
pip install idx2numpy
```

Comment: any way to get separated images and not mixed?

Comment: Nice end-to-end tutorial. This utility works not only with the Digits mnist, but also with Fashion mnist, too (found here -- https://github.com/zalandoresearch/fashion-mnist); or any other idx formatted file.

Answer (score 16):

**install idx2numpy**

```
pip install idx2numpy
```

**Downloading the data**

Download the MNIST dataset from the [official website](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/).

**Decompressing the data**

Ultimately, you should have the following files:

```
train-images-idx3-ubyte
train-labels-idx1-ubyte
t10k-images-idx3-ubyte
t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte
```

**Using idx2numpy**

```
import numpy as np
import idx2numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

imagefile = 'train-images.idx3-ubyte'
imagearray = idx2numpy.convert_from_file(imagefile)

plt.imshow(imagearray[4], cmap=plt.cm.binary)
```

[image: The mnist picture]

Comment: Excellent. I tried most of the answers and only this one works perfectly.

Answer (score 15):

```
import gzip
import numpy as np


def training_images():
    with gzip.open('data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz', 'r') as f:
        # first 4 bytes is a magic number
        magic_number = int.from_bytes(f.read(4), 'big')
        # second 4 bytes is the number of images
        image_count = int.from_bytes(f.read(4), 'big')
        # third 4 bytes is the row count
        row_count = int.from_bytes(f.read(4), 'big')
        # fourth 4 bytes is the column count
        column_count = int.from_bytes(f.read(4), 'big')
        # rest is the image pixel data, each pixel is stored as an unsigned byte
        # pixel values are 0 to 255
        image_data = f.read()
        images = np.frombuffer(image_data, dtype=np.uint8)\
            .reshape((image_count, row_count, column_count))
        return images


def training_labels():
    with gzip.open('data/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz', 'r') as f:
        # first 4 bytes is a magic number
        magic_number = int.from_bytes(f.read(4), 'big')
        # second 4 bytes is the number of labels
        label_count = int.from_bytes(f.read(4), 'big')
        # rest is the label data, each label is stored as unsigned byte
        # label values are 0 to 9
        label_data = f.read()
        labels = np.frombuffer(label_data, dtype=np.uint8)
        return labels
```

Comment: What is the meaning of 'big' in 'from_bytes()' function?

Comment: 'big' means big endian which defines the byte order. In big endian the most significant byte of the word is stored in smaller memory address.

Comment: Can I change np.uint8 to np.float32? When I did this, the number of images changed to 15000, instead of 60000.

Answer (score 1):

here directly a function for you ! (it loads in binary format .ie 0 or 1).

```
def load_mnist(train_data=True, test_data=False):
    """
    Get mnist data from the official website and
    load them in binary format.

    Parameters
    ----------
    train_data : bool
        Loads
        'train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz'
        'train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz'
    test_data : bool
        Loads
        't10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz'
        't10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz' 

    Return
    ------
    tuple
    tuple[0] are images (train & test)
    tuple[1] are labels (train & test)

    """
    RESOURCES = [
        'train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz',
        'train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz',
        't10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz',
        't10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz']

    if (os.path.isdir('data') == 0):
        os.mkdir('data')
    if (os.path.isdir('data/mnist') == 0):
        os.mkdir('data/mnist')
    for name in RESOURCES:
        if (os.path.isfile('data/mnist/'+name) == 0):
            url = 'http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/'+name
            r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
            open('data/mnist/'+name, 'wb').write(r.content)

    return get_images(train_data, test_data), get_labels(train_data, test_data)


def get_images(train_data=True, test_data=False):

    to_return = []

    if train_data:
        with gzip.open('data/mnist/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz', 'r') as f:
            # first 4 bytes is a magic number
            magic_number = int.from_bytes(f.read(4), 'big')
            # second 4 bytes is the number of images
            image_count = int.from_bytes(f.read(4), 'big')
            # third 4 bytes is the row count
            row_count = int.from_bytes(f.read(4), 'big')
            # fourth 4 bytes is the column count
            column_count = int.from_bytes(f.read(4), 'big')
            # rest is the image pixel data, each pixel is stored as an unsigned byte
            # pixel values are 0 to 255
            image_data = f.read()
            train_images = np.frombuffer(image_data, dtype=np.uint8)\
                .reshape((image_count, row_count, column_count))
            to_return.append(np.where(train_images > 127, 1, 0))

    if test_data:
        with gzip.open('data/mnist/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz', 'r') as f:
            # first 4 bytes is a magic number
            magic_number = int.from_bytes(f.read(4), 'big')
            # second 4 bytes is the number of images
            image_count = int.from_bytes(f.read(4), 'big')
            # third 4 bytes is the row count
            row_count = int.from_bytes(f.read(4), 'big')
            # fourth 4 bytes is the column count
            column_count = int.from_bytes(f.read(4), 'big')
            # rest is the image pixel data, each pixel is stored as an unsigned byte
            # pixel values are 0 to 255
            image_data = f.read()
            test_images = np.frombuffer(image_data, dtype=np.uint8)\
                .reshape((image_count, row_count, column_count))
            to_return.append(np.where(test_images > 127, 1, 0))

    return to_return


def get_labels(train_data=True, test_data=False):

    to_return = []

    if train_data:
        with gzip.open('data/mnist/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz', 'r') as f:
            # first 4 bytes is a magic number
            magic_number = int.from_bytes(f.read(4), 'big')
            # second 4 bytes is the number of labels
            label_count = int.from_bytes(f.read(4), 'big')
            # rest is the label data, each label is stored as unsigned byte
            # label values are 0 to 9
            label_data = f.read()
            train_labels = np.frombuffer(label_data, dtype=np.uint8)
            to_return.append(train_labels)
    if test_data:
        with gzip.open('data/mnist/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz', 'r') as f:
            # first 4 bytes is a magic number
            magic_number = int.from_bytes(f.read(4), 'big')
            # second 4 bytes is the number of labels
            label_count = int.from_bytes(f.read(4), 'big')
            # rest is the label data, each label is stored as unsigned byte
            # label values are 0 to 9
            label_data = f.read()
            test_labels = np.frombuffer(label_data, dtype=np.uint8)
            to_return.append(test_labels)

    return to_return
```

Answer (score 1):

**Mass convert to PNG files**

https://github.com/myleott/mnist_png/blob/400fe88faba05ae79bbc2107071144e6f1ea2720/convert_mnist_to_png.py contains a good PNG extraction example, licensed under GPL 2.0. Should be easy to adapt to other output formats with a library like Pillow.

They also have a pre-extracted archive at: https://github.com/myleott/mnist_png/blob/master/mnist_png.tar.gz?raw=true

Usage:

```
wget \
 http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz \
 http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz \
 http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz \
 http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
gunzip --keep *-ubyte.gz
python3 -m pip install pypng==0.20220715.0
./convert_mnist_to_png.py . out
```

And now `out/` contains files such as:

out/training/0/1.png

[image]

out/training/0/21.png

[image]

out/training/1/3.png

[image]

out/training/1/6.png

[image]

out/testing/0/10.png

[image]

out/testing/0/13.png

[image]

convert_mnist_to_png.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import struct
import sys

from array import array
from os import path

import png

# source: http://abel.ee.ucla.edu/cvxopt/_downloads/mnist.py
def read(dataset = "training", path = "."):
    if dataset is "training":
        fname_img = os.path.join(path, 'train-images-idx3-ubyte')
        fname_lbl = os.path.join(path, 'train-labels-idx1-ubyte')
    elif dataset is "testing":
        fname_img = os.path.join(path, 't10k-images-idx3-ubyte')
        fname_lbl = os.path.join(path, 't10k-labels-idx1-ubyte')
    else:
        raise ValueError("dataset must be 'testing' or 'training'")

    flbl = open(fname_lbl, 'rb')
    magic_nr, size = struct.unpack(">II", flbl.read(8))
    lbl = array("b", flbl.read())
    flbl.close()

    fimg = open(fname_img, 'rb')
    magic_nr, size, rows, cols = struct.unpack(">IIII", fimg.read(16))
    img = array("B", fimg.read())
    fimg.close()

    return lbl, img, size, rows, cols

def write_dataset(labels, data, size, rows, cols, output_dir):
    # create output directories
    output_dirs = [
        path.join(output_dir, str(i))
        for i in range(10)
    ]
    for dir in output_dirs:
        if not path.exists(dir):
            os.makedirs(dir)

    # write data
    for (i, label) in enumerate(labels):
        output_filename = path.join(output_dirs[label], str(i) + ".png")
        print("writing " + output_filename)
        with open(output_filename, "wb") as h:
            w = png.Writer(cols, rows, greyscale=True)
            data_i = [
                data[ (i*rows*cols + j*cols) : (i*rows*cols + (j+1)*cols) ]
                for j in range(rows)
            ]
            w.write(h, data_i)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print("usage: {0} <input_path> <output_path>".format(sys.argv[0]))
        sys.exit()

    input_path = sys.argv[1]
    output_path = sys.argv[2]

    for dataset in ["training", "testing"]:
        labels, data, size, rows, cols = read(dataset, input_path)
        write_dataset(labels, data, size, rows, cols,
                      path.join(output_path, dataset))
```

Inspecting the generated PNGs with:

```
identify out/testing/0/10.png
```

gives:

```
out/testing/0/10.png PNG 28x28 28x28+0+0 8-bit Gray 256c 272B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

so they appear to be Grayscale and 8-bit, and therefore should faithfully represent the original data.

Tested on Ubuntu 22.10.

Answer (score -4):

I had the same issue.

Whenever i unzipped the files into executables the extension was not removed so I had:

```
train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
```

Whenever I removed the:
`.gz`,
I had:

```
train-images-idx3-ubyte
```

This fixed my issue.