# How to call function from other class with self?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, wxpython, self

One post right before mine, I found some Code I would like to use. There is an ComboPopup which has checkboxes in it. If one of These checkboxes is activated, I want to pass the selected text back to my class (i.e. `MyForm`). There is an StaticText called `self.text`. I want to Change the Label with the choosen Text of the ComboPopup.

I tried it with:

```
    test = MyForm()
    MyForm.OnUpdate(test,item.GetText())
```

as I thought that `self.text` is parent from `MyForm()`. But that doesn't work. No errors, but also no changes of the text.

What is `self` in this case? Is there a good way to find out what `self` is ? Like print the Name or anything :-)

My Code:

```
import wx
import wx.stc
from wx.lib.mixins.listctrl import CheckListCtrlMixin, ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin

class CheckListCtrl(wx.ListCtrl, CheckListCtrlMixin, ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, style=wx.LC_REPORT | 
                wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        CheckListCtrlMixin.__init__(self)
        ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin.__init__(self)
        self.SetSize(-1, -1, -1, 50)

    def OnCheckItem(self, index, flag):
        item = self.GetItem(index)
        if flag:
            what = "checked"
        else:
            what = "unchecked"
        print(f'{item.GetText()} - {what}')

        test = MyForm()
        MyForm.OnUpdate(test,item.GetText())


class ListViewComboPopup(wx.ComboPopup):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.ComboPopup.__init__(self)
        self.lc = None
    def AddItem(self, txt):
        self.lc.InsertItem(0, txt)
    def Init(self):
        self.value = -1
        self.curitem = -1
    def Create(self, parent):
        self.lc = CheckListCtrl(parent)
        self.lc.InsertColumn(0, '', width=90)
        return True
    def GetControl(self):
        return self.lc
    def OnPopup(self):
        wx.ComboPopup.OnPopup(self)
    def GetAdjustedSize(self, minWidth, prefHeight, maxHeight):
        return wx.ComboPopup.GetAdjustedSize(
            self, minWidth, 110, maxHeight)

class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Popup Menu")
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)

        vsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        comboCtrl = wx.ComboCtrl(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, "Select Text")    
        popupCtrl = ListViewComboPopup()
        comboCtrl.SetPopupControl(popupCtrl)

        popupCtrl.AddItem("Text One")

        self.txt = wx.StaticText(self.panel,-1,style = wx.ALIGN_LEFT)
        self.txt.SetLabel("Startup Text")

        vsizer.Add(comboCtrl,1,wx.EXPAND)
        vsizer.Add(self.txt,1,wx.EXPAND)

        self.panel.SetSizer(vsizer)

    def OnUpdate(self, txt):
        self.txt.SetLabel(txt) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `wx.Frame` subclass instance does not have a parent. You explicitly create it without one:

```
wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Popup Menu")
```

You create an instance of `MyForm` in your `__name__ == '__main__'` block:

```
frame = MyForm().Show()
# Note: your name 'frame' holds the return value of the method Show(), i.e. a boolean
# This probably should rather read:
# frame = MyForm()
# frame.Show()
```

*This* is the `MyForm` instance you show in your `app`.
What you do here:

```
test = MyForm()
```

is creating a *new* instance of `MyFrame` (that has nothing to do with the one your app shows). You then call `onUpdate` on that *new* instance of your `MyForm` class

```
MyForm.OnUpdate(test,item.GetText())
```

Since you never `Show()` that new instance, you can't see the effect of your operation. However, you probably don't want/need that new instance anyway.
You need *your* instance from the `main` block.

There is a `parent` argument on the `CheckListCtrl` initializer. This might contain a chain of objects which you probably can ascend until you reach your `MyForm` instance.
I can't tell for sure, since it is not visible where and how this is called in the `ListViewComboPopup`:

```
def Create(self, parent):
    self.lc = CheckListCtrl(parent)
```

Do a `print(self.Parent)` in `OnCheckItem` to see what it contains and then add another `.Parent` to `self.Parent` until you hopefully end up on a `<__main__.MyForm instance [...]>`. This is where you want to call the `onUpdate` Method. That should look similar to this:

```
self.Parent.Parent.Parent.OnUpdate(item.GetText())
# the number of '.Parent' my vary, based on where in the chain you find your MyForm instance
```

**Edit**
As per the OP's comment, the parent attribute on `wx` objects is spelled with a capital `P`. The respective code snippets have been updated accordingly.

Comment: `self.Parent.Parent.Parent.OnUpdate(item.GetText())`(upper case P at Parent) did the trick! Thanks for the answer! Would you mind to Review my Code and Show where i can do better? I get your Explanation but i really want to get behind making my Code better.

Comment: Ah .. uppercase attribute names. Ok, that was not obvious from reading the docs. Good you found that! Code reviews are better suited over at [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and I'm not really familiar with `wx`. Your code looks quite OK, honestly, except for that `frame = MyForm().Show()` I mentioned. It's a bit strange to see old-style calls to parent class initializers, but the `wx` docs do that all over the place, so it might be related to that package ...

Comment: I will take a look on CodeReview! Many thanks. Also i will Change `frame = MyForm().Show()`. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what wx library does but there is a way to check where .text is.

> You want vars() mixed with pprint():
>
> ```
> from pprint import pprint
> pprint(vars(your_object))
>
> pprint(your_object) # this is OK too
> ```

Suggestion 2

```
type(x).__name__
```

This gets you the class name of an instance. You could insert this line before self.text. And give self as argument instead of x.

Original: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/193539/8471995)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. WX is a GUI Toolkit. And your Code just gives me an empty dict. And you fourth line gives me this `<wx._core.StaticText object at 0x000001E1F4E32438>))`