# Display dictionary in print statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Is there a way to print the contents of a dictionary without have to iterate over the dictionary? In javascript you can console.log to view the contents of the object. Is there something similar in python?

I've tried print statement as well as object.keys() and object.values(). However, I would like to see the entire dictionary via print statement.

```
print(dictionary)
```

I expect `{a: 1}` instead of `object at 0x7efd79610278>`

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192109/is-there-a-built-in-function-to-print-all-the-current-properties-and-values-of-a

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a built-in function to print all the current properties and values of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192109/is-there-a-built-in-function-to-print-all-the-current-properties-and-values-of-a)

Comment: What is `object`? What version of Python?

Comment: @skam Object is a dictionary. Python version is Python3

Comment: Please give more context on how this `object` is created. Add more code for a [mcve].

Comment: Your dictionary is not a dict. How did you create it?

Comment: what does "type(dictionary)" give you?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the variable `dictionary` is what you think it is.
Here's a small example in the Python3 REPL (Read. Evaluate. Print. Loop) that shows the printing a dictionary with the expected behavior.

```
$ python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr  3 2019, 05:39:12) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = {}
>>> a[0] = '0'
>>> a
{0: '0'}
>>> print(a)
{0: '0'}
```

To answer your question the default `__str__` method pronounced (dunder str) should be sufficient. However if it is not you could do something the following and provide your own implementation.

```
>>> import json
>>> class MyDict(dict):
...     def __str__(self):
...             return json.dumps(self)
... 
>>> d = MyDict()
>>> d['key'] = 'value'
>>> print(d)
{"key": "value"}
```