# How to store an object with different data types to an array in Python?

Tags: python

I have an object that has int and string, i.e.:

```
obj1 = Object("cat",(1,2),(2,2))
```

I want to create an `array` that could store `obj1`. I have searched online and realized that Python array could only contain 1 data type.

However, is there any other ways to create an array that could store an object with different data type?

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean Python `list`? Of course it can store objects of various types...

Comment: ***"I have searched online and realized that Python array could only contain 1 data type. "*** - Search again. Here's 3 datatypes (int, float and string) inside the same `list`: `a = [1, 2.2, 'python']`

Comment: Try pasting `my_list = ["cat", (1,2), (2,2)]` into a python interpreter. It's completely valid Python.

Comment: @AndrejKesely Sorry I mean Array. Is it possible to store the object to an array?

Comment: What, **exactly** do you mean by array? Generally, you would use a `list` in Python, arrays being rather esoteric in the language. If you want to store heterogenous data types, then you should *almost certainly* be using a `list`.

Comment: Do you mean an array defined by the [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#module-array) module? All the elements in one have to be the same numeric type.

Answer (score 2):

You can use python list:

```
obj1 = Object("cat",(1,2),(2,2))
my_objects = []
my_objects.append(obj1)
```

Comment: @Paolo Mossini May I ask let say in my_objects, how do I print out obj1's value? I tried to print but it returns [<__main__.Object object at 0x031C7050>]

Comment: @Paolo Mossini Nope it doesn't work, it shows me '[<__main__.Object object at 0x031C7050>]'

Comment: @PaoloMossini May I know how I can paste the code as it is?

Comment: class Object:

    # class constructor
    def __init__(self,name,topL,bottomR):
        self.name = name
        self.topL = topL
        self.bottomR = bottomR

Comment: To print the object values you can use: `print(my_objects[0].name)` `print(my_objects[0].topL)`  `print(my_objects[0].bottomR)`

Comment: @PaoloMossini Is there a way if I print(my_objects[0]), it will return [0]'s all values instead of printing one at a time? Thank you

Comment: check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192109/is-there-a-built-in-function-to-print-all-the-current-properties-and-values-of-a) and let me know if it works

Comment: @PaoloMossini Hi it did not work for me, but I have created a function that will display all values when I call the function. Thanks for helping me!!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your mention of  "Python array could only contain 1 data type" relates to [the `array` package of the sdtlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html), which is indeed quite a specialized collection type. The generic builtin "array" type in Python is actually named `list` - as you would have known if you had done [the official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) -, and can of course contain just any kind of object.