# How to view word2vec model

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I just want to be able to see the values in my word2vec model.

I have a  very small corpus. I just want to see exactly what happens in each step for this particular corpus.

A section of my code is below.

```py
word2vec = Word2Vec(corpus, min_count=1)
word_vectors = word2vec.wv 

termsim_index = WordEmbeddingSimilarityIndex(word_vectors)


dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(food)
bow_corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(doc) for doc in food]


similarity_matrix = SparseTermSimilarityMatrix(termsim_index, dictionary)  
docsim_index = SoftCosineSimilarity(bow_corpus, similarity_matrix, num_best=10)
```

So I want to see what exactly is in `word_vectors`,`termsim_index`,`similarity_matrix` , `docsim_index`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see more of what's happening during each function, you should enable logging at the `INFO` level.

But then, each of your created objects have documented properties you can freely examine – either by looking at the gensim docs per class, or using generic Python operations – like those described in other SO questions, such as [Is there a built-in function to print all the current properties and values of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192109/is-there-a-built-in-function-to-print-all-the-current-properties-and-values-of-a).

To give more specific suggestions, you'd have to explain more what exactly you "want to see".

Comment: I would like to see for example the values in ```termsim_index```. So from what I understand the ```WordEmbeddingSimilarityIndex``` function calculates cosine similarities. I would like to see the numbers that were calculated.

Comment: And just typing ```print(termsim_index)``` does not work.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean in this context? Did you try the options in the answer I linked, to show the properties/values/methods of the object, then drill down into those individually? Generally to understand the internals of an object like that, you would also want to review its source code, either in your local installation or in the online repo at <https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/27bbb7015dc6bbe02e00bb1853e7952ac13e7fe0/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py#L1387>.

Comment: Most of the options from the link give me the following output : ```'<gensim.models.keyedvectors.WordEmbeddingSimilarityIndex object at 0x00000284E3EE0DD8>'```.  I get this when I use a simple print statement too. I want to see the array with the cosine similarities. I want to know exactly what is in there.

Comment: I want to see the mapping between the entities and the vectors.

Comment: Did you try the options in the answer I linked, to show the properties/values/methods of the object, then drill down into those individually? But also, if what you really want to see is specific term-to-term similarities, the use of these `Index` classes isn't strictly necessary or even advised. You may want to use methods on the `word_vectors` object, like `most_similar()` and `similarity()`, instead.

Comment: And finally, if you're truly curious about what's in an object, there's no getting around looking at the source code – the code for `WordEmbeddingSimilarityIndex` is barely 20 lines, & pretty much just calls the word-vectors `most_similar()`. It doesn't have any "array with the cosine similarities"!

Comment: Aaa ok thank you. I will just go and look at the source code.