# Discord.py - 'Member' object has no attribute 'channel'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm just getting started to discord.py and i'm trying to create a very simple bot that plays an mp3 audio from my local storage. So basically the bot should join a voice channel and play the mp3. Here is my code:

```
import discord
import ffmpeg
from discord.ext import commands
import datetime

from urllib import parse, request
import re

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', description="This is a Helper Bot")

@bot.command(name="test")
async def test(ctx):
    # Gets voice channel of message author
    voice_channel = ctx.author.channel
    channel = None
    if voice_channel != None:
        channel = voice_channel.name
        vc = await voice_channel.connect()
        vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe", source=r"PATH"))
        # Sleep while audio is playing.
        while vc.is_playing():
            sleep(.1)
        await vc.disconnect()
    else:
        await ctx.send(str(ctx.author.name) + "is not in a channel.")
    # Delete command after the audio is done playing.
    await ctx.message.delete()

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('pong')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))



bot.run('MYKEY')
```

I found the `test` function here on SO, but i'm having problems using it. When i call it from discord, i get the following error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'channel'
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: `ctx.author.channel` does not seem to have attribute named channel if the exception is correct, to validate this have a look here to print the properties: https://stackoverflow.com/a/193539/7968203

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `discord.Member` instance does not have an attribute called `channel`. It does however have an attribute named `voice` which is an instance of `Optional[VoiceState]`, see https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=voice_state#discord.Member.voice

That `voice` object has an attribute called `channel` which is an instance of `Optional[VoiceChannel]`, see https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=voice_state#discord.VoiceState.channel