# Python PrettyPrinter shows object address but not the contents

Tags: python, pretty-print, python-telegram-bot

I am trying to pretty-print a python object by calling:

```
from pprint import pprint
...
pprint(update)
```

But the output looks like this:

```
<telegram.update.Update object at 0xffff967e62b0>
```

However, using Python's internal `print()` I get the correct output:

```
{'update_id': 14191809, 'message': {'message_id': 22222, 'date': 11111, 'chat': {'id': 00000, 'type': 'private', 'username': 'xxxx', 'first_name': 'X', 'last_name': 'Y'}, 'text': '/start', 'entities': [{'type': 'bot_command', 'offset': 0, 'length': 6}], 'caption_entities': [], 'photo': [], 'new_chat_members': [], 'new_chat_photo': [], 'delete_chat_photo': False, 'group_chat_created': False, 'supergroup_chat_created': False, 'channel_chat_created': False, 'from': {'id': 01010101, 'first_name': 'X', 'is_bot': False, 'last_name': 'Y', 'username': 'xxxx', 'language_code': 'en'}}}
```

Is there a way to make `pprint()`, show the object-data correctly and formatted?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a built-in function to print all the current properties and values of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192109/is-there-a-built-in-function-to-print-all-the-current-properties-and-values-of-a)

Comment: `pprint(update.__str__())`?

Comment: @PacketLoss Unfortunately the answers to that question do not provide the behavior I'm looking for. Still, the data printed by the `print()` function is more complete.

Comment: @CryptoFool You can't `pprint` a string. Well, you can, but it will only line wrap it. Also don't call `__str__` directly but use `str(...)` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pprint` uses the representation (`__repr__()` method) of the object while `print` uses `__str__()`. What you see in `print` output is **not** a dictionary but a string representation of the inner structure of the `telegram.update.Update` instance.

There is no generic solution to this, but since your question is about a specific library, consulting [the relevant docs](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.telegramobject.html) shows that there is a `.to_json()` method, so you can do this:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

...
pprint(json.loads(update.to_json()))
```