# How to get all and only properties of an object in Python?

Tags: python

I want to get all the **properties** of an object, and with this I mean only methods decorated with `@property`.

Answers to similar questions like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192109/is-there-a-built-in-function-to-print-all-the-current-properties-and-values-of-a) return all attributes and/or methods without filtering those which are properties.

Comment: What happened when you tried using one of those methods, and then filtering to check which of the attributes are properties? (Hint: `property` is itself a *class*, so you can simply use type-checking.)

Comment: That said, I think that answering this question will not be as useful to you as you expect.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying this `[attr for attr in dir(object) if isinstance(getattr(object,attr),type(property))]` but it is not working. It only returns `['__doc__', '__module__']` and this object has properties I have defined.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what is the expected result you want, but you can filter the methods that are from the class `property`. For example:

```py
class A:

    def bla(self):
        pass

    @property
    def ble(self):
        pass

list(
    filter(
        lambda f: isinstance(f[1], property),
        vars(A).items()
    )
)

# Result
# [('ble', <property at 0x7f01149074a8>)]
```

Comment: Sorry, just a categorical dv for using filter with a lambda and even calling list on it.