# How would I deal with an attribute error with mediapipe solutions?

Tags: python, mediapipe

I get an attribute error if I use the function:

```
def faceDetection():
   if results.detections:
      for detection in results.detection:
         print(id, detection)
```

> AttributeError: type object 'SolutionOutputs' has no attribute
> 'detections'

is the error I get if I try running, specifically it calls it on the results.detections: line
it works fine in this [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=01sAkU_NvOY&t=23323s&ab_channel=freeCodeCamp.org)
at 1:43:56
I don't really know how to read the github code but [here's](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/master/mediapipe/python/solutions/face_detection.py) the link
I do have

```
mpFD = mp.solutions.face_detection # FD = face_detection
fD = mpFD.FaceDetection()
```

defined before the function already.
Is this an issue with my code or is it something else?

Comment: See what the 'results' object does have by inspecting it with something like the vars function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192109/is-there-a-built-in-function-to-print-all-the-current-properties-and-values-of-a

Answer (score 0):

This error depends on the Python version you are using. You need to use the version minimum `Python 3.9` but most probably you are using Python 3.6.

It would be better to create an environment with `conda` by specifying Python version and install `mediapipe` in there and try to run your code again. The error will disappear.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WByJ24wmB7A&t=237s) is an example how to establish environment to run mediapipe examples.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't a problem with the mediapipe library, but I hadn't initialized results as the faceDetections solutions, but I had results as a value for the hands solution module.